# React tailwind css connected to state not working

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a sidebar with a display style that changes from 'none' to 'block' based on the user clicking the Tasks button:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [sidebarDisplay, setSidebarDisplay] = React.useState<string>("none");
  const handleSetSidebarDisplay = () => {
    setSidebarDisplay((display) => (display === "none" ? "block" : "none"));
  };
  return (
    <div className="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col bg-background">
      <div className="flex-1 bg-slate-600 relative flex">
        <div
          className={`w-64 bg-slate-200 flex-initial relative display:${sidebarDisplay}`}
        >
          <div className="w-4 absolute top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 -right-7 -rotate-90">
            <Button onClick={handleSetSidebarDisplay}>Tasks</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <main className="flex-1 bg-slate-950"></main>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But nothing is happening when I click the button, any idea why?

I'm also not the greatest with frontend programming so if UI experts can tell me what I'm doing wrong in terms of the css/html, it would also be super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Furthermore, `display:` is not a Tailwind variant (unless you have some custom Tailwind configuration that you have not provided that registers this). Neither is `none` a Tailwind utility class (unless you have some custom setup that registers this too) – did you perhaps mean the `hidden` class that applies `display: none`?

If you *did* mean to apply this custom `display:` variant to the `block` and `none` class, *and* this `none` is defined in your Tailwind setup, consider applying the `display:` variant to the strings used:

```
const [sidebarDisplay, setSidebarDisplay] = React.useState<string>("display:none");
const handleSetSidebarDisplay = () => {
  setSidebarDisplay((display) => (display === "display:none" ? "display:block" : "display:none"));
};
return (
  <div className="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col bg-background">
    <div className="flex-1 bg-slate-600 relative flex">
      <div
        className={`w-64 bg-slate-200 flex-initial relative ${sidebarDisplay}`}
      >
```

If you *did* mean to apply this custom `display:` variant to the `block` and `hidden` (not `none`) class, consider applying the `display:` variant to the strings used:

```
const [sidebarDisplay, setSidebarDisplay] = React.useState<string>("display:hidden");
const handleSetSidebarDisplay = () => {
  setSidebarDisplay((display) => (display === "display:hidden" ? "display:block" : "display:hidden"));
};
return (
  <div className="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col bg-background">
    <div className="flex-1 bg-slate-600 relative flex">
      <div
        className={`w-64 bg-slate-200 flex-initial relative ${sidebarDisplay}`}
      >
```

Otherwise, if you *do not* have any custom configuration that registers this `display:` variant or `none` class, consider removing the prefix altogether and use `hidden` instead of `none`:

```
const [sidebarDisplay, setSidebarDisplay] = React.useState<string>("hidden");
const handleSetSidebarDisplay = () => {
  setSidebarDisplay((display) => (display === "hidden" ? "block" : "hidden"));
};
return (
  <div className="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col bg-background">
    <div className="flex-1 bg-slate-600 relative flex">
      <div
        className={`w-64 bg-slate-200 flex-initial relative ${sidebarDisplay}`}
      >
```